# How to solve the double meaning of "Must be"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, modal-verbs, modality

> The papers must be blue

1. This sentence means: I have not seen the papers but I'm sure they are blue.
2. If it's an instruction, it means: You must use blue papers. Any other color will not work.

Am I right about the double meaning? If yes, how to solve the confusion?

Comment: _Mary had a little lamb_ has a so-called [double meaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYsup.jpg), too. When you provide no additional context, no additional meaning can be deduced.

Comment: @J.R. True, it would be easier to say for certain which it is from context. However that would mean answers addressed a very specific niche question that the OP should have been able to deduce themselves. This sentence could be said out of context, perhaps by a very monotone tutor. I think the question is very interesting as it is, and quite valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The papers must be blue"

Yes, you are correct that this sentence could mean either:

- I have not seen the papers but I'm sure they are blue.
- You *must* use blue papers.

A previous answer correctly advises that *context* is the only way to tell them apart. That is true if the words are written *or* spoken, but there may be other ways to tell *and to express* the difference if you were the one saying or writing it.

It is of course quite hard to explain the nuances of spoken expressions, but if spoken I would expect there to be different emphasis on the word "must". I would interpret it as an **order** if this word was spoken:

- with "certainty",
- with a strong, determined emphasis,
- with *no* emphasis, or "matter-of-fact".

On the other hand I would interpret it as a statement of expectation or hopefulness if the word "must" was spoken:

- with "uncertainty",
- with an exaggerated expression of hopefulness
- perhaps with an uncertain facial expression.

In *written* form some writers may add *italics* to emphasise words, so you may see:

> The papers *must* be blue.

But this doesn't really differentiate between the two different types of verbal emphasis I detailed above.

An exclamation mark may also be used to denote emphasis, but again this could be ambiguous. The sentence is not really a question with either intended meaning because it does not solicit an answer, so either way it could be an exclamation. A good novel writer would add some description to the way a character was speaking so the reader could understand the intended meaning, and it is possible that in creative writing a question mark would be added, even though not technically a question, because this denotes the verbal emphasis in a creative way.

A sure way of expressing the sentence to denote the uncertainty would be:

> **Surely** the papers must be blue?

Answer (score 2):

Context.

There is really no other way.
Both your examples work, for a given context.

Answer (score 1):

> The papers must be blue.

It shows confidence, yet, consciousness of a degree of uncertainty, in parallel.

The verb:

> to be

softens the modality of auxiliary verbs. Their meanings become synonymous.

can be,
could be,
may be, 
might be,
should be,
must be.

**Instructions** **are not usually given using the passive voice.** You should use an active or imperative sentence, for more efficiency:

> You must use blue papers.
>
> Use blue paper!

These sentences are just given as examples, and could be (may be, should be, must be) out-of-context.